# Error creating " Access.Application" Object on Visual Basic with Office 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have created a application that takes an Excel file and inserts it into my access database table.
I used Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library in my computer . But when I executed the application it in an another computer with Access 2007 it stops immediately. This is the code:

```
Private Sub xlsTomdb()
    On Error GoTo err_handler
    Dim oAccess As Access.Application
    Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    oAccess.Visible = False
    oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase App.Path + "\archivi.mdb", True
    oAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "EXCEL", App.Path + "\Export\Final.xls", True
    oAccess.Quit
err_handler:
      MsgBox "The code failed at line " & Erl, vbCritical
End Sub
```

The msgBox shows "The code failed as line 0". When I removed the Error Handler the program continues the execution normally.
While running the program on another PC with Office 2007 it terminates at this function with runtime error [-2147467259 (80004005) microsoft odbc microsoft access driver type mismatch in expression]

This function is executed on button click event.
Is there any reason not to open access 2007, because I used Access 2013 while building it?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Any reason why you have not declared the oAccess object?

Comment: the declaration is at the top of of the code, this is only the function

Comment: Please update the code with the declaration. Also where are you executing this function from? Application is Access?

Comment: You could try `Dim oAccess As Object` instead of `Dim oAccess As Access.Application`

Comment: I notice that you have a spelling error on 'Acccess.Application' Have you tried to compile your code, and is that realllly the way it is spelled?

Comment: @Wayne, no I misspelled only here. Otherwise vb would tell that there is a error at that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EBalla:

"Microsoft Access 15.0 Object" or DAO 15 library belongs to office 2013. Earlier versions will not know about this library. if your target machines are using office 2007 you need to add the reference "Microsoft Access 12.0 Object library" into your project. You are experiencing compatibility issue rather than code issue.

also check this out:
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-38.html

Comment: I only have one Office installed on my machine. It is not required do have many Office versions, for each target machine. When I build the project setup, the Wizard also copied a reference of my version of MSAcces.exe and uses it to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute the follow sentence...
Its work fine with any interop referenced in Project...

from:

```
Dim oAccess As Access.Application
Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
```

to:

```
Dim oAccess As object
Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
```